# Logical construction of proof

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove the following two statements. Although, I'm having trouble seeing its logical construction.

$(1)$ If $r$ is rational $(r\ne0)$ and $x$ is irrational, then prove that $rx$ is irrational.

$P:=$ "$r$ is rational $(r\ne0)$ and $x$ is irrational."

$Q:=$ "$rx$ is irrational."

($P$ $\land$ $\lnot$$Q$) $\Rightarrow$ $c$

$(2)$ If $n \ge N$, then $|f_n(x) − f(x)|\le 3$ for all $x \in A$.

I have two questions:

For $(1)$, is the logical construction I've created for a proof by contradiction correct?

For $(2)$, is the statement an implication?

Comment: (2) can be written as $n\geq N\Longrightarrow \forall x\in A,\ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq 3$. For (1) by $c$ you mean contradiction?

Comment: yes, for $c$ I mean contradiction.

Comment: Usually you write $\bot$ for contradiction, but yes and yes.